# Some SVN tasks ..remote local sync etc

Tags: svn, synchronization, svn-hooks, svn-client

Here is the setup, many windows client machines access local SVN server (ubuntu) in LAN.

The local SVN server is also connected to internet but windows clients are not connected.

There is a remote SVN server  (ubuntu) to which I need all the repositories of the local SVN mirrored one way.

I.e if any update or commit or any change whatsoever happens on the local SVN I need those to happen on the remote SVN server too. Is this possible ?

Windows client machines CANNOT connect to the remote SVN server at all.

Can someone provide me the actual hooks or any scripts that is required ?

I'm even ok with  a cron job running once per day on the local SVN server updating the remote SVN server ? If so what are the steps and where I need to start looking ?

Shanthi

Answer (score 0):

- Set up a local repository with Apache and mod_dav_svn. Make sure the path of the repository is the same for remote and local repository*.
- Set its UUID to that of the remote repository.
- Use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to mirror the remote repository to the local one and run it regularly to keep them in sync.
- Use the *SVNMasterURI* setting in the config of the local mirror to configure it to send all write-requests to the remote server.

* more specifically, make sure that just the path on the mirror does not contain the remote path

A quick search brought up [another tutorial](http://www.tty1.net/blog/2007-08-26-subversion-proxy_en.html) about this.